# UIButton with different titles in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parsing, uibutton

I am making an Instagram clone , my home screen looks like this :

[image]

you can see the "name" buttons in the cells. My Parse query is as follows:

```
var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var isLiking = [String:Bool]()


func loadData() {

    data.removeAllObjects()

    var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    if let post = object as? PFObject {

                        self.data.addObject(object)
```

now i want to set the titles of `UIButtons` in `tableViewCell` as the `userNames` i am getting from the query in `data` (`NSMutableArray`) as `String` to get the userNames with their respective posts. I am trying this because if user clicks on the `name` button, segue will happen and will jump in the respective user profile. So my questions are:

1. Is this the way of doing it? or we should use something else instead of `UIButton`?
2. If this is the correct way then how can i achieve my goal?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want the name to be what the user presses to segue to the user profile, then a `UIButton` is fine.
2. You can achieve this by setting the title `UIButton` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function in your `ViewController`:

   ```
   cell.yourButton.setTitle(userNames[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do like this. If you are using the PFQueryTableViewController, you can retrieve the username like this:

```
NSString *name = [object objectForKey: @"whoTook"];
[cell.yourButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```